# Pegar valor no forEach do JSP no JQuery para exibir em label

Tags: jquery, jsp, foreach

Gostaria de ajuda para pegar um valor que está setado dentro de um `forEach` na minha JSP, jogar para o Jquery e este exibir numa `label` na mesma página.

Esse `forEach` recupera uma lista direta do banco de dados. Usei um `hidden` para resgatar o valor que preciso, o: `lista.deTipo`. Acontece que esse laço percorre duas vezes no banco, mas quando pego esse valor pelo o `id` do `hidden` ele só retorna o primeiro valor do `deTIpo`. O restante ele não pega e não to sabendo percorrer esse laço do lado do JQuery para pegar esses dois valores para `lista.deTipo`.

Segue o código da jsp `registrar.jsp`:

```
<html:radio name="formulRadio" property="nuTipo" styleId="radioTipo" value="1"/>&nbsp;Tipo Interno&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <html:radio name="formulRadio" property="nuTipo" styleId="radioTipo" value="2"/>&nbsp;Tipo Externa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<c:forEach var="lista" items="${form.listaPo}" varStatus="listaMotivo" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="deTipo" id="deTipo" value="${lista.deTipo}">
                </c:forEach>
```

No js `registra.js`

```
$('#form input:radio').bind("click", function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var tipo = $("input[@name='formulRadio']:checked").value;
        tipo = parseInt($(this).val());

        if(tipo == "2"){
            mensagemAlerta("Radio tipo externo acionado."+tipo,"INF");
                var deTipo = $("#deTipo").val();
                document.getElementById("descMotivo").innerHTML = deTipo;
    }
        else if(tipoTce =="1"){

            var deTipo = $("#deTipo").val();
            mensagemAlerta("Radio externa acionado."+deTipo,"INF");         
                document.getElementById("descMotivo").innerHTML = deTipo;   
        }
}});
```

Comment: Por que você está usando jstl + jquery? Você está checando um input:radio e não o radio do jstl. Use o radio do JQuery (https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) para não misturar os componentes. Acredito que deve funcionar fazendo apenas essa troca.

Comment: Obrigada, vou trocar! Esse projeto já existe e eu sou iniciante. Então estou com muitas dúvidas.